# show articlelist within single article in joomla

Tags: php, joomla1.5

Hello I am looking for showing article list within single article.

e.g. If have category list layout and  I have one category name "Sports".
whenever I click on this category I want to show there subcategories such as

1.Cricket
2.Football
3.Tennis
4.Hockey

Is there any component/module/plugin available for this please suggest me.Hoe I can show this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Its a good option to use K2 component instead of this joomla article with section & category model. With K2 you can make any hierarchy of content items and list them in whatever way you want.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/content-construction/8061
check this. If you meant to do it another way please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for solution but I don't want to add new module if you have any solution by changes in existing code then suggest me.

Comment: "Is there any component/module/plugin available for this please suggest me" - Thats what you asked and hence I gave a answer like this. I will check will this. I think its also can be done with article itself.